# How to create a custom textview which looks like a "received message" layout,using XML

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to create something that looks like a "received message" text view[image: .]

Comment: have you tried this as background

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a **BACKGROUND IMAGE** as you want like you show in question.

than after try something like

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDate"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMsgFrom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="test message"
        android:textColor="@color/lblFromName"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblMsgFrom"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bubble_corner" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_msg_from"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimeFrom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtMsgFrom"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtMsgFrom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMsgFrom"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/d5"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgFrom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lblMsgFrom"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="test message"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout >
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mob_no"
        android:background="@drawable/yourImage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```